# How to find most efficient approximation of a real number with combination of positive and negative powers of two?

Tags: approximation

I need to approximate a real number $x$ as a sum of some set of positive and negative powers of two, e.g.

$$ x = \delta_0 2^{n_0} + \delta_1 2^{n_1} + \delta_2 2^{n_2} + \ldots $$

where each $\delta_i$ is $-1$ or $+1$ and each $n_i$ is some integer.  Basically, I keep adding or subtracting smaller and smaller powers of two until I get close enough.

For example,
$$ x=0.5937 \approx 2^{-1} + 2^{-3} - 2^{-5}=0.59375 $$
and I could keep going to get closer.  Note, I'm interested in reals, not integers, and especially $x\in (0,1)$.

The reason I want this is to do multiply by an *a priori* known constant digitally using shifting and sums, not proper multipliers.  I've been picking these out by hand but this seems like it should be a well known algorithm.  Please help.

Comment: If $-1$ is allowed, the result is not unique, e.g. $2^{-1} + 2^{-3} - 2^{-5} = 2^{-1} + 2^{-4} + 2^{-5}$. We can just convert $x$ to regular binary, and use the $-1$ to help reduce the chains of $1$'s, e.g. $2^{-2} + 2^{-3} + 2^{-4} + 2^{-5} = 2^{-1} - 2^{-5}$.

Comment: Any number can be expressed in binary, octal, decimal, hexadecimal. or any other base.

Comment: @player3236 Yes, I realize this.  Is there a way to automate this process?